# How to substitute string into expression which accesses Json object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to express `fileName = req.files.raymond.originalFilename;`
But I don't know if it is "raymond" beforehand.
So, I have to substitute a variable into the expression
(req.body.key has the name I need )

```
const name = req.body.key;
const fileName = req.files.name.originalFilename;
```

But this way of substitution doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You must be getting some error in your console. Pl. share what error are you getting.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
req.files[name].originalFilename
```

Comment: bingo bango answered